# How to get multiple lines out of a file by a regex?

Tags: shell, sed, grep

How to get multiple lines out of a file by a regex?

I often would like to get multiple lines / modify multiple lines by a regex. A example case:

I am trying to read part of an XML/SGML file (they are not necessarily well formed or in a predictable syntax, so a regex would be safer than a proper parser. In addition I would like to be able to do this also whit completely unstructured files where just some key words are known.) in a shell script (running on Solaris and Linux).

Example XML:

```
<tag1>
 <tag2>bar</tag2>
</tag1>
<tag1>
 <tag2>foo</tag2>
</tag1>
```

From this I would like to read the `<tag1>` if it contains `foo` somewhere within it.

A regex like `(<tag1>.*?foo.*?</tag1>)` should give the right part but tools like `grep` and `sed` only work for me with single lines. How can I get

```
<tag1>
 <tag2>foo</tag2>
</tag1>
```

in this example?

Comment: [Mandatory link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454)

Comment: @evilsoup Thats true, but my question is not specifically about XML/SGML files, just about any text files.

Answer (score 8):

If you have GNU grep installed you could do multiline search by passing in the `-P` (perl-regex) flag and activating `PCRE_DOTALL` with `(?s)`

```
grep -oP '(?s)<tag1>(?:(?!tag1).)*?foo(?:(?!tag1).)*?</tag1>' file.txt
<tag1>
<tag2>foo</tag2>
</tag1>
```

If the above doesn't work on your platform, try passing the `-z` flag in addition, this forces grep to treat NUL as line separator, causing the entire file to look like a single line.

```
grep -ozP '(?s)<tag1>(?:(?!tag1).)*?foo(?:(?!tag1).)*?</tag1>' file.txt
```

Comment: This gives no output on my system when run on the OP's example file.

Comment: Works for me. +1. Thanks for the `(?s)` tip

Comment: @terdon, what version of GNU grep are you running?

Comment: @1_CR `(GNU grep) 2.14` on Debian. I copied the OPs example as is (adding only final newline) and ran your `grep` on it but got no results.

Comment: @terdon, you are probably running an older version of `pcre`. `pcretest -C` should reveal the version. I am on GNU grep 2.5.1

Comment: @1_CR I could not find `pcretest`, the equivalent on my system seems to be `pcre-config --version` which returns `8.31`. Since I have a significantly newer version of `grep` I also assume I have a newer version of PCRE. Which one do you have?

Comment: This didn't work for me either. I'm on `PCRE version 8.10 2010-06-25`. Fedora 14, and I had the tool `pcretest`.

Comment: I just tried this on Ubuntu 12.04, 12.10, and CentOS 6 and it didn't work on any of those either. Also 12.04 did not have `pcretest`, just `pcre-config`. 12.10 had neither.

Comment: @slm, i am on pcre 6.6, GNU grep 2.5.1 on RHEL. Do you mind trying `grep -ozP` instead of `grep -oP` on your platforms?

Comment: @1_CR - the `-grep -ozP` fixed it on all of them!

Comment: @terdon, edited the answer and added one more option

Comment: Nice, +1, did not know about `-z`.

Comment: I'm no whiz with sed, but it has a modifier N which adds a newline to the pattern space and then appends the next line of input to the pattern space. I think this will also allow you to search for things across more than one line. It's documented in info sed.

Answer (score 3):

```
#begin command block
#append all lines between two addresses to hold space 
    sed -n -f - <<\SCRIPT file.xml
        \|<tag1>|,\|</tag1>|{ H 
#at last line of search block exchange hold and pattern space 
            \|</tag1>|{ x
#if not conditional ;  clear buffer ; branch to script end
                \|<tag2>[^<]*foo[^\n]*</tag2>|!{s/.*//;h;b}
#do work ; print result; clear buffer ; close blocks
    s?*?*?;p;s/.*//;h;b}}
SCRIPT
```

If you do the above, given the data you show, before that last cleanup line there, you should be working with a `sed` pattern space that looks like:

```
 ^\n<tag1>\n<tag2>foo</tag2>\n</tag1>$
```

You can print out your pattern space whenever you like with `l`ook. You can then address on `\n` characters.

```
sed l <file
```

Will show you each line `sed` processes it at the stage in which `l` is called.

So I've just tested it and it needed one more `\backslash` after the `,comma` in the first line, but otherwise works as is. Here I put it in a `_sed_function` so I can easily call it for demonstration purposes throughout this answer: *(works with comments included, but are here removed for brevity's sake)*

```
_sed_function() { sed -n -f /dev/fd/3 
} 3<<\SCRIPT <<\FILE 
    \|<tag1>|,\|</tag1>|{ H
        \|</tag1>|{ x
            \|<tag2>[^<]*foo[^\n]*</tag2>|!{s/.*//;h;b}
    s?*?*?;p;s/.*//;h;b}}
#END
SCRIPT
<tag1>
 <tag2>bar</tag2>
</tag1>
<tag1>
 <tag2>foo</tag2>
</tag1>
FILE


_sed_function
#OUTPUT#
<tag1>
 <tag2>foo</tag2>
</tag1>
```

Now we'll switch the `p` for an `l` so we can see what we're working with as we develop our script and remove the non-op demo `s?` so the last line of our `sed 3<<\SCRIPT` just looks like:

```
l;s/.*//;h;b}}
```

Then I'll run it again:

```
_sed_function
#OUTPUT#
\n<tag1>\n <tag2>foo</tag2>\n</tag1>$
```

Ok! So I was right - that's a good feeling. Now, let's shuffle our `l`ook around to see the lines it pulls in but deletes. We'll remove our current `l` and add one to the `!{block}` so it looks like:

```
!{l;s/.*//;h;b}

_sed_function
#OUTPUT#
\n<tag1>\n <tag2>bar</tag2>\n</tag1>$
```

That's what it looks like just before we wipe it out.

One last thing I want to show you is the `H`old space as we build it up. There are a couple of key concepts I hope I can demonstrate. So I remove the last `l`ook again and alter the first line to add a peek into `H`old space at the end:

```
{ H ; x ; l ; x

_sed_function
#OUTPUT#
\n<tag1>$
\n<tag1>\n <tag2>bar</tag2>$
\n<tag1>\n <tag2>bar</tag2>\n</tag1>$
\n<tag1>$
\n<tag1>\n <tag2>foo</tag2>$
\n<tag1>\n <tag2>foo</tag2>\n</tag1>$
```

`H`old space *survives* line cycles - hence the name. So what people often trip up on - ok, what *I* often trip up on - is that it needs deleting after you use it. In this case I only e`x`change once, so the hold space *becomes* the pattern space and vice-versa and this change also *survives line cycles.*

The effect is that I need to delete my hold space which used to be my pattern space. I do this by first clearing the current pattern space with:

```
s/.*//
```

Which simply selects every character and removes it. I cannot use `d` because this would end my current line cycle and the next command would not complete, which would pretty much trash my script.

```
h
```

This works in a similar way to `H` but it *overwrites* hold space, so I've just copied my blank pattern space over the top of my hold space, effectively deleting it. Now I can just:

```
b
```

out.

And that's how I write `sed` scripts.

Comment: Thanks @slm! Youre a really ok guy, you know that?

Comment: Thanks, nice job, very quick ascent to 3k, next up 5k 8-)

Comment: I dunno, @slm. Im beginning to see im learning less and less here - maybe ive outgrown its usefulness. I gotta think about it. ive barely even come to the site last couple weeks.

Comment: At least get to 10k. Everything worth unlocking is at that level. Keep chipping away, 5k will come fairly quick now.

Comment: @slm - Maybe - but that gets harder. The more i learn the less interested i become in the `sl` questions and the less popular my answers are to the harder questions. How do you do it? And Gilles, too - you guys are both seasoned pros - how do you continue addressing the same kinds of questions without getting bored?

Comment: I treat them as puzzles when I get there, which I do, it's hard not to when you're A'ering the same Q for the 5th time about iptables and such. The best Q's are the ones where we have 10-12 A's actually. I try to think of all the ways I can solve it using every technology I can . It's akin to tying your hand/arm behind your back and doing something. I actually used to do martial arts and to me it's like a kata or doing something with blindfolds on. I started doing these A's on a dare that I couldn't get to 3k on this site so don't give up.

Comment: If you need a break from the site take it but don't disappear either. We've had others that have come and gone, but your A'ers are extremely unique in their approach so we'd hate to lose ya!

Comment: Well, @slm - youre a rare breed anyway. I do agree about the multiple answers though. Thats why it bugs me when some qs get closed. But that rarely happens, actually. Thanks again, slm.

Answer (score 2):

@jamespfinn's answer will work perfectly well if your file is as simple as your example. If you have a more complex situation where `<tag1>` could span more than 2 lines, you'll need a slightly more complex trick. For example:

```
$ cat foo.xml
<tag1>
 <tag2>bar</tag2>
 <tag3>baz</tag3>
</tag1>
<tag1>

 <tag2>foo</tag2>
</tag1>

<tag1>
 <tag2>bar</tag2>

 <tag2>foo</tag2>
 <tag3>baz</tag3>
</tag1>
$ perl -ne 'if(/<tag1>/){$a=1;} 
            if($a==1){push @l,$_}
            if(/<\/tag1>/){
              if(grep {/foo/} @l){print "@l";}
               $a=0; @l=()
            }' foo.xml
<tag1>

  <tag2>foo</tag2>
 </tag1>
<tag1>
  <tag2>bar</tag2>

  <tag2>foo</tag2>
  <tag3>baz</tag3>
 </tag1>
```

The perl script will process each line of your input file and

- `if(/<tag1>/){$a=1;}` : the variable `$a` is set to `1` if an opening tag (`<tag1>`) is found.
- `if($a==1){push @l,$_}` : for each line, if `$a` is `1`, add that line to the array `@l`.
- `if(/<\/tag1>/)` : if the current line matches the closing tag:

  - `if(grep {/foo/} @l){print "@l"}` : if any of the lines saved in the array `@l` (these are the lines between `<tag1>` and `</tag1>`) matches the string `foo`, print the contents of `@l`.
  - `$a=0; @l=()` : empty the list (`@l=()`) and set `$a` back to 0.

Comment: This works well except in the case where there are more than one <tag1> containing "foo". In that case it prints every thing from the beginning of the first <tag1> to the end of the last </tag1>...

Comment: @den I tested it with the example shown in my answer which contains 3 `<tag1>` with `foo` and it works fine. When does it fail for you?

Comment: it feels so wrong parsing xml using regex :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `sed` alternative:

```
sed -n '/<tag1/{:x N;/<\/tag1/!b x};/foo/p' your_file
```

**Explanation**

- `-n` means do not print lines unless instructed.
- `/<tag1/` first matches the opening tag
- `:x` is a label to enable jumping to this point later
- `N` adds the next line to the pattern space (active buffer).
- `/<\/tag1/!b x` means if the current pattern space contains no closing tag, branch to the `x` label created earlier. We thus keep adding lines to the pattern space until we find our closing tag.
- `/foo/p` means if the current pattern space matches `foo`, it should be printed.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with GNU awk I think, by treating the end tag as a *record separator* e.g. for a known end tag `</tag1>`:

```
gawk -vRS="\n</tag1>\n" '/foo/ {printf "%s%s", $0, RT}'
```

or more generally (with a regex for the end tag)

```
gawk -vRS="\n</[^>]*>\n" '/foo/ {printf "%s%s", $0, RT}'
```

Testing it on @terdon's `foo.xml`:

```
$ gawk -vRS="\n</[^>]*>\n" '/foo/ {printf "%s%s", $0, RT}' foo.xml
<tag1>

 <tag2>foo</tag2>
</tag1>

<tag1>
 <tag2>bar</tag2>

 <tag2>foo</tag2>
 <tag3>baz</tag3>
</tag1>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your file is structured exactly as you have shown above, you could utilize  the -A (lines after) & -B (lines before) flags for grep... for example:

```
$ cat yourFile.txt 
<tag1>
 <tag2>bar</tag2>
</tag1>
<tag1>
 <tag2>foo</tag2>
</tag1>
$ grep -A1 -B1 bar yourFile.txt 
<tag1>
 <tag2>bar</tag2>
</tag1>
$ grep -A1 -B1 foo yourFile.txt 
<tag1>
 <tag2>foo</tag2>
</tag1>
```

If your version of `grep` supports it, you could also use the simpler `-C` (for context) option which print the surrounding N lines:

```
$ grep -C 1 bar yourFile.txt 
<tag1>
 <tag2>bar</tag2>
</tag1>
```

Comment: Thanks, but no. This is only a example and the real stuff looks pretty unpredictable ;-)

Comment: That's not finding a tag with foo in it, that's just finding foo and displaying lines of context

Comment: @NathanWallace yes, which is exactly what the OP was asking for, this answer works perfectly well in the case given in the question.

Comment: @terdon that's not at all what the question asks. Quote: "I would like to read the <tag1> if it contains foo somewhere within it." This solution is like "I would like to read 'foo' and 1 line of context regardless of where 'foo' appears". Following your logic, an equally valid answer to this question would be `tail -3 input_file.xml`. Yes it works for this specific example, but it's not a helpful answer to the question.

Comment: @NathanWallace my point was that the OP specifically stated this is not a valid XML format, in that case, it could well have been sufficient to print the N lines around the string the OP is searching for. With the information available, this answer was decent enough.

Comment: @NathanWallace Actually I tried to do this more than once already and it wasn't always a XML file. I extended the question about that.